# iLogic error due to Level of Detail is not a custom Level of Detail

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

After required project execution like crating inventor assembly model and drawing there is an ilogic error. After assembly document open LastActiveDesignViewRepresentation: Default and LastActiveLevelOfDetailRepresentation: iLogic

How to resolve this forge "INTERACTION" issue? Please note "DesignPluginLocally" module executing without any issues.

```
----------LOG----------------

[05/17/2021 11:22:33] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[DADockPlateConfig].path)\" /p  \"$(args[DocumentParams].path)\" /i \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\" "
]
"Settings":{
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695"
"ActivityId":"l985BAIkBOLjzDVAeN9amG0lry4peAru.DADockPlateConfig+alpha"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Inventor!26"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"l985BAIkBOLjzDVAeN9amG0lry4peAru.DADockPlateConfig!1"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "InventorDoc": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "DockPlateMaster",
    "pathInZip": "Dock Plate Master.iam",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:szgQFcfJE670aN7IqwYX9Tf+soE=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:QjRhcmX3ApJAyUpOyrvcQKOZq+o="
    }
  },
  "DocumentParams": {
    "localName": "documentParams.json",
    "url": "data:application/json, {\"BoardType\":\"\\\"A\\\"\",\"Width\":\"41 in\",\"Length\":\"51 in\",\"Reefer\":\"false\",\"SpecialLip\":\"true\",\"LipLength\":\"10 in\",\"BendAngle\":\"11 deg\",\"EZRoll\":\"true\",\"SpeedyBoard\":\"true\",\"SpecialLeg\":\"true\",\"LegLength\":\"7 in\",\"RemoveLeg\":\"false\",\"UniqueDrawingNumber\":\"\\\"012422\\\"\"}"
  },
  "OutputZip": {
    "localName": "DockPlateResult.zip",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:mAcsWgDdhwNNRCWP4+v74/4ZkAY=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:QjRhcmX3ApJAyUpOyrvcQKOZq+o="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"l985BAIkBOLjzDVAeN9amG0lry4peAru\"},\"scope\":\"code:all\",\"expires_in\":3573,\"client_id\":\"l985BAIkBOLjzDVAeN9amG0lry4peAru\"}"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 900,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
}
[05/17/2021 11:22:33] Starting work item 91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695
[05/17/2021 11:22:33] Start download phase.
[05/17/2021 11:22:33] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/l985baikboljzdvaen9amg0lry4pearudonotdelete_vsn_kaali_input/objects/Dock Plate Master.zip'
[05/17/2021 11:22:33] Embedded resource [ {"BoardType":"\"A\"","Width":"41 in","Length":"51 in","Reefer":"false","SpecialLip":"true","LipLength":"10 in","BendAngle":"11 deg","EZRoll":"true","SpeedyBoard":"true","SpecialLeg":"true","LegLength":"7 in","RemoveLeg":"false","UniqueDrawingNumber":"\"012422\""}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\documentParams.json.
[05/17/2021 11:22:34] '18114509' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\zip_2295.zip.
[05/17/2021 11:22:34] End downloading file 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/l985baikboljzdvaen9amg0lry4pearudonotdelete_vsn_kaali_input/objects/Dock Plate Master.zip'.
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\zip_2295.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster.
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] End download phase successfully.
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] Command line: [ /al "T:\Aces\Applications\ad2a4ef0248f7b80d41245b0e6aeaa73.l985BAIkBOLjzDVAeN9amG0lry4peAru.DADockPlateConfig[1].package" /p  "T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\documentParams.json" /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.iam" ]
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] Start script phase.
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] ### Command line arguments: /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695 "T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\userdata" /exe "T:\Aces\AcesRoot\25.00\coreEngine\Exe\InventorCoreConsole.exe"  /al "T:\Aces\Applications\ad2a4ef0248f7b80d41245b0e6aeaa73.l985BAIkBOLjzDVAeN9amG0lry4peAru.DADockPlateConfig[1].package" /p  "T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\documentParams.json" /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.iam" .
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] Start Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : InventorCoreConsole.exe: 25.0.18300.0, 461-7e71832
[05/17/2021 11:22:36] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Starting Inventor Server.
[05/17/2021 11:22:37] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Started Inventor Server 2021.1 (Build 251245000, 245) (25, 10, 24500, 0000)
[05/17/2021 11:22:37] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[05/17/2021 11:22:37]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[05/17/2021 11:22:37]     iLogic Plugin: initializing...
[05/17/2021 11:22:37] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[05/17/2021 11:22:37] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting up iLogicLogLevelTo: Warn
[05/17/2021 11:22:37] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Creating default project file with name: FDADefault at T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695
[05/17/2021 11:22:37] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating default project T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\FDADefault.ipj
[05/17/2021 11:22:37] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opening document: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.iam Invisible mode: False
[05/17/2021 11:22:38] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opened
[05/17/2021 11:22:38] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Getting Inventor plug-in.
[05/17/2021 11:22:38] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Plug-in: DADockPlateConfigPlugin
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: DADockPlateConfigPlugin
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : DADockPlateConfigPlugin (1.0.0.0): initializing... 
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Executing 'RunWithArguments' method on Automation object.
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Processing T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.iam
[05/17/2021 11:22:38] LastActiveDesignViewRepresentation: Default
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : after open LastActiveDesignViewRepresentation: Default
[05/17/2021 11:22:38] LastActiveLevelOfDetailRepresentation: iLogic
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : after open LastActiveLevelOfDetailRepresentation: iLogic
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>>> We have an assembly file! <<<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Reading param file T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\documentParams.json
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: BoardType, "A"
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting BoardType to "A"
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: Width, 41 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:38]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting Width to 41 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: Length, 51 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting Length to 51 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: Reefer, false
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting Reefer to false
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: SpecialLip, true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting SpecialLip to true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: LipLength, 10 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting LipLength to 10 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: BendAngle, 11 deg
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting BendAngle to 11 deg
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: EZRoll, true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting EZRoll to true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: SpeedyBoard, true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting SpeedyBoard to true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: SpecialLeg, true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting SpecialLeg to true
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: LegLength, 7 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting LegLength to 7 in
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: RemoveLeg, false
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting RemoveLeg to false
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  Parameter name and value: UniqueDrawingNumber, "012422"
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting UniqueDrawingNumber to "012422"
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:39]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Getting full file name of assembly
[05/17/2021 11:22:41]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> after rebuild<<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:41]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> after update 2<<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:44]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Saving updated assembly
[05/17/2021 11:22:44]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> STP BEFORE <<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:44]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> STP AFTER SAVEAS STP <<<T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.stp
[05/17/2021 11:22:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : dwgPath: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.idw
[05/17/2021 11:22:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> IDW BEFORE UPDATE 2 <<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> IDW AFTER UPDATE 2 <<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:48]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> IDW AFTER SAVE2 <<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> IDW AFTER SAVEAS PDF <<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> IDW CLOSE <<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : >>> IAM CLOSED <<<
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : stepsourceFile: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.stp
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : stepdestinationFile: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateResult\Dock Plate Master.stp
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : pdfsourceFile: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.pdf
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : pdfdestinationFile: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateResult\Dock Plate Master.pdf
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : stepsourceFile file exists: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.stp
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : pdfsourceFile file exists: T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateMaster\Dock Plate Master.pdf
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Zipping up T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateResult.zip
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Zip File saved as T:\Aces\Jobs\91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695\DockPlateResult.zip
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Warning: 0 : Inventor message: Published with a warning(s)
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Warning: 0 : Inventor inner xml: <Warning Message="Cannot create font Century Schoolbook" />
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]  Context: RuleRunning 
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]  Details: System.ArgumentException: Component.IsActive: Cannot change the suppression state of component Paint Strip Left:1.
[05/17/2021 11:22:55] The active Level of Detail in Dock Plate Master.iam is not a custom Level of Detail.
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at iLogic.ComponentInRule.set_IsActive(Object componentName, Boolean valb)
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at ThisRule.Main()
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]  Context: RuleRunning 
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]  Details: System.ArgumentException: Component.IsActive: Cannot change the suppression state of component Leg:1.
[05/17/2021 11:22:55] The active Level of Detail in Dock Plate Master.iam is not a custom Level of Detail.
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at iLogic.ComponentInRule.set_IsActive(Object componentName, Boolean valb)
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at ThisRule.Main()
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: DADockPlateConfigPlugin
[05/17/2021 11:22:55]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : DADockPlateConfigPlugin: deactivating... 
[05/17/2021 11:22:55] Processing failed
[05/17/2021 11:22:56] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/17/2021 11:22:56] Error: Application InventorCoreConsole.exe exits with code -1 which indicates an error.
[05/17/2021 11:22:56] End script phase.
[05/17/2021 11:22:57] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[05/17/2021 11:22:57] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[05/17/2021 11:22:57] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/l985BAIkBOLjzDVAeN9amG0lry4peAru/91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3PIPC6ZLL&Expires=1621340553&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDjexoaq72PfJUurkAmhTQyl07HakTbgLYH8y0kUCb3yQIhANJZzyT3%2FYPEzhHZSG5XvWq%2FE%2Bzud18B6TMSHbahgONBKtUBCEQQAhoMMjIwNDczMTUyMzEwIgx7ruDN87g9rnHxIB8qsgFCzaWDVOaQ4VJ%2B%2BtuRRXYtGkn1PuzzE9Rv1GalGKhZwGlVVc%2FS8%2FXBNxEGRq3TEt2aLIMIJ5DIbb54t%2BKlWxMnFuYoB4x1BL94iffJhKJnZiVUgPuqcZrCLj54rwL28FD6zrPFLv6d%2B1BdCbIH2CXedSHAN44SUewRKNI%2Fp4Q5tUNC1iYeFKHrRrmm4zsbrOAtidEKEL3jZ6zQoQlj0c79zlj7GrzIY0nYBfzeT7MSGbuGMN%2BaiYUGOt8BjiQzqMFuCvwq43Ygyo%2BwfN8z0IxuYpxCSaDCNahMguRMV1HuYY0k7sauv9va1aFbFMkQtKG5Fakmd0sTMnWxhD387dFYTuUHeGIs2xjRzXL6uLwx82Eb%2BAWm6uQB00jE19WPO54LobFtEsVYXQQYEq%2FEVn%2FlqmjxNbzcIWoi7UOUz3%2F0UJ5JpgjVsa35DaX%2BMcqeAT%2FtG0QqZqS9XxyGFE%2B923k7%2FHNpl%2FvjJKTMDI%2BWKT7QJCmWzb6N8sGFlJthTU7Dx2wHcM6u57P4MjMFJfRKl%2FPcOhC%2Bpo769RKfmw%3D%3D&Signature=JSCV2JNDB30pr9zFcdS9dR69yzY%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2021-05-17T11:22:33.2294585Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2021-05-17T11:22:33.3967212Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2021-05-17T11:22:36.4399573Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2021-05-17T11:22:56.9681405Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 18114773
  },
  "id": "91a53e5a97b443d49430568181fc8695"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues regarding component suppression on DA (Design Automation) when the document is opened `IsVisble=True` which is currently the default both in Inventor on the desktop and DA: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dealing-suppressed-components

Please try adding the `/iv` switch to the `commandLine` to open the document with `IsVisible=False`
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/cmdLine/cmdLine-inventor/

Looking further at the report, I assume you are opening the relevant LOD of the model programmatically using `Open()`/`OpenWithOptions()` - so just pass `IsVisible=False` to it.

Also, if you are opening the document programmatically anyway, you do not need to use the `/i` switch in the command line.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.  I am bit confused with adding /iv parameter. I tried adding it after inventordoc path.
  "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /al /iv \"$(appbundles[DADockPlateConfig].path)\" /p  \"$(args[DocumentParams].path)\" /i \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\"   /iv

Comment: pls ignore /iv after /al

Comment: When opening documents programmatically (that's what InventorCoreConsole is doing as well), you have to specify the LOD to use otherwise Master is used. The "LastActiveLevelOfDetailRepresentation: iLogic" does not mean that the file is **currently** opened with **iLogic LOD**. It just means that when it was last saved, that was the active LOD.
If you want to open the document with the LOD that was last active and you don't know the name in advance, then programmatically find out what was the last active LOD and open it using OpenWithOptions() - you don't need /i switch in the commandLine

Comment: Thanks adam. Yes, I am setting the required LOD before opening.

NameValueMap openOptions = app.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap();
openOptions.Add("DesignViewRepresentation", "Default");
openOptions.Add("LevelOfDetailRepresentation", "iLogic");

doc = app.Documents.OpenWithOptions(assemblyPath, openOptions,false);

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you have this in the **commandLine** if you are opening the document yourself programmatically? `/i \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\"`

Comment: Adam - I am using a web application to run against my appbundle using APIs. I am using the Interaction application for testing. The issue has been resolved now. I have moved level of representation code to iLogic and its running when I open the iam file in forge. Thanks for your help.